# Can we say ECEF datum like in Geodetic datum?

Tags: coordinate-system, datum, geodetic, ecef

Commonly we use geodetic datum to describe the geoid, a distorted ellipsoid model of the Earth, but is it correct to say Earth-Centered Earth-Fixed (ECEF) datum?

Because we are applying ECEF to a sphere model of the Earth.  Datum is the applied model, such as sphere, ellipsoid, or geoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the geodetic community, a geoid is a equipotential surface that roughly matches mean sea level if there was no topography.

You might want to take a look at this [IERS site](http://itrf.ensg.ign.fr/general.php) on the difference between ITRS and ITRF. ITRS, International Terrestrial Reference System, is the theoretical world system, which is then realized using a set of control points into an International Coordinate Reference Frame. They are always in ECEF (3D Cartesian), and in fact only acquire a [particular ellipsoid like GRS80](http://itrf.ensg.ign.fr/faq.php?type=answer#question2) when you need to convert the XYZ coordinates into latitude-longitude-ellipsoidal height values.

So back to your question. I would probably not use datum nor geodetic datum, but instead reference frame.